# How can i download data in a file getting by ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting data from a url and now i want to download this in a file using jquery. What should i do?

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'some_url',
      type: 'GET'

    }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data)
    $('#container').html(data);
  })
```

Comment: What format is the data in the response? JSON?

Comment: i am getting a db in json

Comment: Why not just make a link or redirect to the URL?

Comment: What do you use on Server side?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a text file, you can do:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "your_url_here/filename_here",
        dataType : 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Comment: i am doing the same thing. i am getting data from url. and write it in console.log.... But i want to download all the data in another file

Comment: You mean you would like to retrieve the data in the file @ URL, then download the content into a local file?

Comment: Via javascript on a browser, you won't be able to create a file into a local directory; you may be able to trigger the download of the file directly, which will dump the file into the designated "Download" directory set by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to download the data, force a file download try this;
You shouldn't need jQuery for this;

```
window.location="url";
```

Or if you already have the data client side something like this should work;

```
 if (navigator.appName != 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
{
    window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(data));
}
else
{
    var popup = window.open('','mydata','');
    popup.document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + data + '</pre>';
}
```

Here is a link to how you can do this;
http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/11/download-json-to-csv-using-javascript/

Comment: i am already getting data. Now i want to save this data in another file in my folder

Comment: A file in a folder on the local machine? Not sure you can do that...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

Comment: yes.. file is on my local machine or i can create a file through it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger a download from an AJAX request since it violates the same origin rule request, basically the browser itself needs to trigger the download either by a form or an iframe pointing to the download script. I would Create an iframe with src="path_to_script/download?blah=blah&blah=blah" that would download it.

Comment: Once you get your data inside your success function, you could append a new iframe with the src property pointing to the script. You will have to change the way you are looking at this since your AJAX call wont be able to get the data and give it to you as a file. Is hard to write you a piece of code since from little data I have you might as well don't even need to make an ajax call, maybe just bind a click event to a button and with JavaScript append the iframe.

Answer (score -1):

By download, you mean write to a file stored in your hard disk? If that is the case then I suspect that JS wont be able to do such a thing since internet is not trusted as a source which can tamper content on the hard disk.

But you can try out the code below if writing to a file is your intention.

```
$.get('some url',{},function(data){
  function WriteToFile(sText){
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\test.txt", true);
  s.WriteLine(data);
  s.Close();
  }
})
```

Comment: ActiveXObject is just for Internet Explorer. However, why dont you write a small service which can write the file. You just call the service with an ajax request and send the data as a input parameter there. As soon as the ajax operation is finished, redirect to that file which would automatically download it.